# How can one prove that the sequence of $n$ 1's followed by $n$ 0's is aperiodic

Tags: sequences-and-series, periodic-functions, sequence-of-function

**Disclaimer:** This is not a homework task. The question arises from genuine curiosity.

I'm trying to prove that the sequence of $n$ 1's followed by $n$ 0's is aperiodic.
Apparently, the corresponding OEIS entry is [A118175](https://oeis.org/A118175).

The first few terms are as follows:
$1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...$

From the OEIS page, I've chosen what seems to be the simplest expression (not claiming that it's indeed the simplest one, with respect to this particuar proof) for the sequence, namely:

$a(n) = 1 - ceiling(sqrt(n+1)) + round(sqrt(n+1))$

My approach is *proof by contradiction*.

Assume that the sequence is periodic and, hence, a period $k$ for $k > 0$ exists.

This implies that:
$a(n) = a(n + k)$

The $1$s cancel out, and what remains is:

$round(sqrt(n+1)) - ceiling(sqrt(n+1)) = round(sqrt(n+k+1)) - ceiling(sqrt(n+k+1))$

For $k < 5$ this causes problems, however, because the results of each pair of LHS-RHS terms may be equal.

This is as far as I've been able to get.

**Update:** Perhaps the fact that all $0 < k < 5$ cases could be exhaustively proven by induction, as irrelevant, be utilized.

For example, as per the periodicity assumption, we have $a(0) = a(k) = 1$ and $a(1) = a(k + 1) = 0$. If $k = 1$, however, a contradiction emerges, because it implies that $a(0) = a(k) = a(1) = 1$.

Then, for $k \ge 5$, it'll follow as per the properties of the $ceiling$, $round$ and $sqrt$ functions.

Comment: Hint : If there were a period, the number of consecutive zeros would be upperbounded.

Comment: Thanks, @Peter! I'll try to think how to embed that within the set of existing assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

It is a mistake to use the ceiling, round, and sqrt functions here -- they just complicate a simple situation. All you need is two facts:

- for any $k$, the sequence contains $k$ consecutive $1$'s;
- the sequence contains an infinite number of $0$'s.

These two facts taken together ensure that the sequence is not periodic with period $k$.

Comment: I'm trying to wrap my head around this statement: "the sequence contains an infinite number of 0's." 

Could you elaborate what it is based upon, please?

Also, would you mind providing some pointers or hints, regarding how I could still try to make the proof work with the ceiling, round and square root functions?

Comment: I have no interest in making the proof work with the ceiling, round and square root functions!

Comment: That's fair enogh. Could you still elaborate on the second bullet point of your answer?

Comment: But Tiag0, it's obvious! Just look at them!

Comment: My bad. I misunderstood that we were just looking at a finite subsequence.

Comment: @Tiag0: what does it mean for a finite sequence to be periodic? Every finite sequence of length $n$ is periodic with period $k$ if $k\ge n$.

Comment: TonyK, I originally misunderstood that your second bullet point applied to only an arbitrary interval $mk$ until $(m+1)k$. That's what gave rise to the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

Notice that the sequence of $n$ ones starts at the position
$$2(1+2+\cdots + (n-1))+1 = (n-1)n+1$$
and the sequence of $n$ zeroes starts $n$ positions further, i.e. $(n-1)n+1+n$.

Let $n \in \Bbb{N}$ be arbitrary. If $a$ were periodic with period $n$ we would have $a(k+n) = a(k)$ for all $k \in \Bbb{N}$. However, the above remark implies that for $k = n(n-1)+1$ holds
$$a(n(n-1)+1) = 1, \quad a(n(n-1)+1+n) = 0$$
so $a$ is not periodic with period $n$.

Comment: I like your approach and have upvoted it. I think there are some inaccuracies in the notation (or it may be my getting confused by the period being referred to as $n$), but following the same idea about starting locations of 1s and 0s, one could arrive at a successful proof by contradiction.